# Google+ share with onendinteraction callback function does not fired

Tags: javascript, google-plus

Good evening everybody.

I have the next code:

```
<body>
....
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-onendinteraction="apply_shared_actions" data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); 
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();

    var apply_shared_actions = function ( response ) { console.log('test_fired'); }
</script>
....
</body>
```

The function apply_shared_actions does not fired.

Please, tell me where I did a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-onendinteraction` is documented as:

> If specified, this function is called when the interaction bubble disappears. You can use this callback function to modify your page, such as resuming a video, when the bubble closes.

With the [announcement](https://plus.google.com/110610523830483756510/posts/Z1FfzduveUo) that Google+ buttons are getting streamlined experiences, there is no longer an interaction bubble to trigger these callbacks.